# Including/excluding files from batch script

Tags: batch-file

In the following batch script for copying the most recently created files from a directory, I would like to include and exclude specific file names, but not sure how to.

```
@echo off

set source="C:\FolderA\FolderB"

set target="C:\FolderC\FolderD"

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%\*.* /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO COPY %source%\"%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END1
:END1

...

set source="C:\FolderE\FolderF" <--- From this directory I would also want to copy, in addition to the most recent file created, the most recent file created that has the word "error" in the file name.

set target="C:\FolderC\FolderD"

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%\*.* /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO COPY %source%\"%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END2
:END2

…

set source="C:\FolderG\FolderH" ***<---From this folder i copy the most recent created file, but would like to exclude the files that contains the word "Graphical" in the file name.***

set target="C:\FolderC\FolderD"

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%\*.* /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO COPY %source%\"%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END3
:END3
```

Is there anyone who could help me please? :)

Comment: Pipe the output of the `Dir` to `Findstr`, checking for the undesired string and use conditional operater `||` to enact the command on files that do not contain the undesried string.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a script that can be called with QUOTED parameters For:

- Arg 1: Dir Switches and Search Pattern
- Arg 2: The String for Findstr to Match
- Arg 3: Conditional Operator `||` or `&&` to execute the following command
- Arg 4: Initalial command syntax to execute on Output of `Dir | Findstr`
- [Optional]: Arg 5: trailing command syntax / string to execute on or append to Output of `Dir | Findstr`

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Param3="
Set "Usage=Echo/%~n0 ^<Pattern^> ^<Match String^> ^<[^|^|]^|[^&^&]^> ^<"Command"^> [String / Command]&Echo/Args 4 or 5 can reference %%G and it's modifiers to access output.&Exit /B 0"
IF "%~4"=="" (%Usage%)
IF "%~3"=="&&" (Set Param3=_)Else IF "%~3"=="||" (Set Param3=_)
If not Defined Param3 (Echo/Invald Param for Operator ^<[^|^|]^|[^&^&]^> & %Usage%)
If Not "%~5"=="" For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Dir %~1 ^|^| ^(Echo/Invalid Dir Options^&Exit /b 0^)')Do Echo/"%%~G" | Findstr /LIC:"%~2" > Nul 2> Nul %~3 ( %~4 %%~G %~5 2> Nul || Echo/ Error in Command Usage: "%~4" %%G "%~5" )
If "%~5"=="" For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Dir %~1 ^|^| ^(Echo/Invalid Dir Options^&Exit /b 0^)')Do Echo/"%%~G" | Findstr /LIC:"%~2" > Nul 2> Nul %~3  ( %~4 %%~G 2> Nul || Echo/ Error in Command Usage: "%~4" %%G )
```

An example of a Usage from the command line:

```
C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop $> $MATCH "/A:-D /B *.bat" "$" "&&" "Echo/[%~tG]         " "                     [%~zG   ]"
[05/09/2020 09:35 PM]            $Array.bat                     [8940   ]
[26/09/2020 12:13 PM]            $base.bat                      [4930   ]
[12/09/2020 04:11 PM]            $Case.bat                      [748    ]
[23/09/2020 11:50 AM]            $compare.bat                   [1737   ]
[12/09/2020 03:10 PM]            $find.bat                      [334    ]
[24/09/2020 12:28 PM]            $game.bat                      [4161   ]
[15/09/2020 02:41 AM]            $Group.bat                     [463    ]
[26/09/2020 02:36 PM]            $in.bat                        [511    ]
[25/09/2020 04:58 AM]            $LA.bat                        [2098   ]
[23/09/2020 10:39 AM]            $label.bat                     [156    ]
[26/09/2020 11:55 AM]            $list.bat                      [1554   ]
[28/09/2020 12:48 AM]            $MATCH.bat                     [744    ]
[23/09/2020 03:55 AM]            $mc2.bat                       [1697   ]
[07/09/2020 01:35 AM]            $nArray.bat                    [1581   ]
[07/09/2020 12:55 AM]            $oldlost.bat                   [1199   ]
[12/09/2020 12:35 AM]            $remstr.bat                    [572    ]
[12/09/2020 12:23 AM]            $remstr2.bat                   [682    ]
[12/09/2020 03:38 AM]            $RGN.bat                       [1277   ]
[12/09/2020 01:36 PM]            $SSM.bat                       [850    ]
[10/09/2020 06:37 AM]            $Str.bat                       [515    ]
[22/09/2020 01:37 AM]            $VT.bat                        [1194   ]
[06/09/2020 11:59 PM]            test$.bat                      [1184   ]
```

Comment: Sorry i am very new at this, how do i incorporate it into the script above?

Comment: Search `batch functions` for information on how to use script as a callable function within batch files. Read also the output  of `call /?` in cmd.exe to learn how to call a label or script.