# Batch File - Excluding certain file types when executing a command to all files in the same folder

Tags: batch-file

Been working on creating a flexible batch script that when you drop it into a folder and run it it will will run it's command on every file in that folder and subfolders but exclude specific file types such as itself. This has proved far more difficult than originally thought and would be thankful for some insight.

Goals of the batch file:

- Running command on files that lack a file extension
- Does run command on files with a file extension
- Relative paths for flexible use when dropped into folders
- Helpful to run through child folders as well, but not required

What me and a colleague have come up with thus far for checking functionality is this:

```
set FILEFORMATS=".bat"".ini"

for %%x in (*) do if /I not %%x == (%FILEFORMATS%) (echo If Not Command) else (echo If Command)
```

The problem we think we're running into is the *if* statement seems to check all files in the folder as a whole and executes based on that instead of checking if the statement is true for each file individually in the folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, wouldn't that be easier to put an 'if' inside loop? When using /I you need ENABLEEXTENSIONS.. And I'm not sure if that if will do the trick, have a look in docs like "If /?", you need comparison operator.
And I am pretty sure FILEFORMATS won't work like an array, its just concatenated string

Comment: `PushD %~dp0` at the beginning of your script will ensure it's running in the directory your .bat is located. Everything else you ask can be achieved by piping the output  of a Dir command to findstr and using conditions operators as exampled and described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64091061/12343998)

Comment: Read the output of `Dir /?` to learn the syntax for searching files, wildcards and switches available to filter the results.

Comment: An alternative would be to use the for loop variable  modifier ~x in combination with sequential if /I not conditional checks on each extension type. Note however,  for readability 
 you should modify your for loop variable to a capital letter that is not a for loop modifier. `For /R %%G in (*.*) Do If /I not "%%~xG"==".bat" If /I Not "%%~xG"==".ini" (command)`

Comment: `/R` being the recursive switch. Read the output of `for /?` in cmd.exe for more.

Comment: @T3RR0R Hey, thanks for pointing in that different direction! Was able to get the bat working with that help but I just had a couple questions since this was the first attempt at bat writing:
-- I wasn't able to find the G referenced in Dir or For /? so I'm wondering where that's from.
-- I'm not sure if the `PushD %~dp0` part you suggested earlier was only for the code I posted since your later example didn't need to use it to work.
-- for the `(*.*)` I read in another post that wildcards only worked at the end of a file path, is this a special case or can they always be used like this?

Comment: Wildcard usage differs by command. If you read the output of `For /?` to the very end it discusses the for variable modifiers  and the reason for using upper case letters to reference files.